# Load different COM Library Versions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, com

I'm using C# and wrote a program that interacts with Corel Draw. Corel Draw offers a COM-Library. During development I used the Version 18.1 (that's the COM-Library from my installed Corel Draw version). I wanted to test my programm on another computer that has a different Corel Draw version installed so the programm fails. But when I change the references to the newer version COM-Library that it works fine, so it seems, that the library is identical.

I use only two references for my project, but I saw, that Corel Draw also offers a .tlb file with these two dlls included.

How can I run my programm on each Version (or more than 1) of Corel Draw?

Comment: Normally, the COM dll should use the same CLSID (class ID) and it should work, independent of which version is installed. What is the error when it fails?

Comment: It's in german: https://image.ibb.co/i8SQdz/Unbenannt.png

Comment: That is all entirely normal, exact same thing happens with a .NET library with the wrong [AssemblyVersion].  Same approach you'd use in .NET, use reflection.  Remove the type library reference from the References node of the project.  Use `dynamic` for the object variables.  Use `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.FromProgId("yadayada"))` to create an object.  Painful to get correct when written from scratch, but you have a tested version now with guaranteed good method and property names.  Thorough testing required, you get a runtime crash when the new version changed a method too much.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to use it and what ProgId is and so on... my class looks like that: https://pastebin.com/FJ9meN2r

Comment: The progid is "CorelDRAW.Application" https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/w/guide/210/8-2-working-with-the-application-object